# Range-base for and insert on a vector C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, auto

Is it possible to change the size of a vector in C++11 while iterating over it? Clearly the iterator will be invalidated, but can the following clean syntax still be used?

```
std::vector<some_type> vec;
for(auto elem : vec) {
   if(condition(elem)) {
      new_elem = function(elem);
      vec.insert(iterator_associated_with_elem+1, new_elem);
   }
   //Don't insert on condition(new_elem)
}
```

If not, what is the cleanest code to accomplish this task?

Comment: It might be interesting to note that this type of code is perfectly valid for all containers for which `insert` doesn't invalidate iterators (such as `std::list`, `std::set` and `std::map`). However, you would have to replace the +1 with `std::next` for types which lack random access iterators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. The standard mandates that the `raged-based for` behaves like a given algorithm. This algorithm uses iterators, which get invalidated when you modify the vector.

The simplest way for me is to to use iterators. Note that when we insert, we also reassign the iterator so that we always have a valid iterator:

```
auto it = vec.begin();
while(it < vec.end()) {
  if (condition(*it)) {
    new_elem = function(*it);
    it = vec.insert(it + 1, new_elem);
  }
  ++it;
}
```

Comment: Actually you can do it with a bit of a hack (see my answer).

Comment: @Danvil When you double a 10,000 -element vector to insert five additional elements, that's not "a bit of a hack" - I'd say that's a hack all the way :-)

Comment: Haven't seen this `it < vec.end()` in a while... Any reason to prefer `<` to `!=` here?

Comment: @dyp it makes more sense to me to have the condition that yields true for the valid positions of the iterator. And I make this a habit so that I avoid bugs in more complicated repetitive structures where the iterator might (due to a bug) jump over the end, never being `==` to the end. It's just a habit and personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I'd rather use `!=` at least in generic code as it works also for non-RaIt. Maybe you can even invert the argument about the bug: `<` can hide a logical flaw in the iteration; iterating past 1-past-the-end is UB anyway.

Comment: @dyp You are right about the hiding of the logical flow. I guess ultimately it comes down that that's how I started using `for` a long time ago (using indexed iteration i.e. `i<n`) and never thought about it twice. I was not aware actually that `!=` is widely used.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use this trick, because there is an iterator behind your range loop. Once that iterator is invalidated, you cannot reference it again.

You can use this construct if you exit the loop immediately after the insertion. Otherwise, you need to use an index-based loop that starts at the back, and goes down to zero to avoid "seeing" elements that have been inserted during the execution of the loop.

```
std::vector<some_type> vec;
for(int i = vec.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
   const some_type& elem(vec[i]);
   if(condition(elem)) {
      vec.insert(vec.begin()+i+1, function(elem));
   }
   //Don't insert on condition(new_elem)
}
```

Comment: Actually you can do it with a bit of a hack (see my answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (auto &val : vec)
    {
        static int i = 0;

        if (val == 5)
        {
            vec.insert(vec.begin() + i + 1, 6);
        }
        ++i;
    }
```

Values of vec will then be: `1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: I don't see why this is wrong :l https://ideone.com/B4iuJD It's the only answer keeping OP's range-based for-loop and it works..

Comment: Because the call to `insert` can invalidate all of the vector's iterators, leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it is wrong because it has undefined behavior: once you call `vec.insert(...)`, the iterator of your range loop becomes invalid. Perhaps it's OK in your code, because the insertion happens only during the last iteration, so the damage is limited. However, in general case you risk to read memory that has been freed by the vector during its expansion.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames It's wrong because of 6.5.4/1 which shows the pseudocode implementation of a range based for. Take a look at that and it'll be evident why.